# global scope and local scope in javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider the following snippet in javascript.
The output of the following snippet is :
The first alert shows "undefined" whereas the second alert shows "2"

```
var a = 1;
function test(){
    alert(a);
    var a = 2;
    alert(a);
}
test();
```

Why does the first alert not show the value of the global variable a which is 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called "hoisting" in JavaScript. Your function is automatically transformed into this one:

```
var a = 1;
function test() {
  var a;
  alert(a);
  a = 2;
  alert(a);
}
test();
```

Nice read about that: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing is [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) in action.

This is how the code is being interpreted:

```
function test(){
    var a; // a === undefined
    alert(a);
    a = 2;
    alert(a);
}
```